# Send Email From Amazon SES in ASP.NET MVC App

Tags: asp.net, sendmail, amazon-ses

I host my web app which is written in .net mvc2 on amazon ec2. currrently use gmail smtp to send email. beacuse of google for startup email quota cant send more than 500 email a day. So decide to move amazon ses. How can use amazon ses with asp.net mvc2? How about configuration etc? Is email will send via gmail? because our email provider is gmail. etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Send Email via Amazon is a right decision. Because when you move to amazon you will immediately get 2000 email free per day which is greater than googla apps 500 emails quota a day.

Step by Step:

1. Go to http://aws.amazon.com/ses
   and click Sign Up for Amazon SES.
2. To get your AWS access identifiers
3. verify your email address - email
   which you will send email via. You
   need perl packages installled on
   your computer to test email
   features.
4. include:amazonses.com to your dns record.

Step by step documentation.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/getting-started.html

There is a Amazon SES (Simple Email Service) C# Wrapper on codeplex you can use this wrapper to send emails.

[Amazon SES C# Wrapper](http://amazonses.codeplex.com/)

Comment: The http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ses/latest/GettingStartedGuide/ link is broken

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way is to download the SDK via Nuget (package is called AWSSDK) or download the SDK from Amazon's site.  The sdk download from their site has an example project that shows you how to call their API to send email.  The only configuration is plugging in your api keys.  The trickiest part is verifying your send address (and any test receipients) but their is an API call there too to send the test message. You will then need to log in and verify those email addresses. The email will be sent through Amazon (that is the whole point) but the from email address can be your gmail address.

Answer (score 2):

@gandil I created this very simple code to send emails

```
using Amazon;
using Amazon.SimpleEmail;
using Amazon.SimpleEmail.Model;
using System.IO;

namespace SendEmail
{
 class Program
 {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Remember to enter your (AWSAccessKeyID, AWSSecretAccessKey) if not using and IAM User with credentials assigned to your instance and your RegionEndpoint
        using (var client = new AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient("YourAWSAccessKeyID", "YourAWSSecretAccessKey", RegionEndpoint.USEast1))
        {
            var emailRequest =  new SendEmailRequest()
            {
                Source = "FROMADDRESS@TEST.COM",
                Destination = new Destination(),
                Message = new Message()
            };

            emailRequest.Destination.ToAddresses.Add("TOADDRESS@TEST.COM");
            emailRequest.Message.Subject = new Content("Hello World");
            emailRequest.Message.Body = new Body(new Content("Hello World"));
            client.SendEmail(emailRequest);
        }
     }
  }
}
```

You can find the code in here https://github.com/gianluis90/amazon-send-email

Answer (score 1):

Following is how I sent email with attachment

```
  public static void SendMailSynch(string file1, string sentFrom, List<string> recipientsList, string subject, string body)
    {

        string smtpClient = "email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"; //Correct it
        string conSMTPUsername = "<USERNAME>";
        string conSMTPPassword = "<PWD>";

        string username = conSMTPUsername;
        string password = conSMTPPassword;

        // Configure the client:
        System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient client = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient(smtpClient);
        client.Port = 25;
        client.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

        System.Net.NetworkCredential credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, password);
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.Credentials = credentials;

        // Create the message:
        var mail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
        mail.From = new MailAddress(sentFrom);
        foreach (string recipient in recipientsList)
        {
            mail.To.Add(recipient);
        }
        mail.Bcc.Add("test@test.com");
        mail.Subject = subject;
        mail.Body = body;
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;


        Attachment attachment1 = new Attachment(file1, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);


        ContentDisposition disposition = attachment1.ContentDisposition;
        disposition.CreationDate = System.IO.File.GetCreationTime(file1);
        disposition.ModificationDate = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(file1);
        disposition.ReadDate = System.IO.File.GetLastAccessTime(file1);

        mail.Attachments.Add(attachment1);

        client.Send(mail);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Download AWSSDK.dll file from internet
   use following name-spaces

> ```
> using Amazon;
> using Amazon.SimpleEmail;
> using Amazon.SimpleEmail.Model;
>
> using System.Net.Mail;
> ```

2 . Add to web config...

```
 <appSettings>
     <add key="AWSAccessKey" value="Your AWS Access Key" />
     <add key="AWSSecretKey" value="Your AWS secret Key" />
 </appSettings>
```

3 . Add a AWSEmailSevice class to your project that will allow to send mail via AWS ses...

```
public class AWSEmailSevice
    {

        //create smtp client instance...
        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();

        //for sent mail notification...
        bool _isMailSent = false;

        //Attached file path...
        public string AttachedFile = string.Empty;

        //HTML Template used in mail ...
        public string Template = string.Empty;

        //hold the final template data list of users...
        public string _finalTemplate = string.Empty;

        //Template replacements varibales dictionary....
        public Dictionary<string, string> Replacements = new Dictionary<string, string>();


        public bool SendMail(MailMessage mailMessage)
        {
            try
            {

                if (mailMessage != null)
                {
                    //code for fixed things
                    //from address...
                    mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("from@gmail.com");

                    //set priority high
                    mailMessage.Priority = System.Net.Mail.MailPriority.High;

                    //Allow html true..
                    mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;

                    //Set attachment data..
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(AttachedFile))
                    {
                        //clear old attachment..
                        mailMessage.Attachments.Clear();

                        Attachment atchFile = new Attachment(AttachedFile);
                        mailMessage.Attachments.Add(atchFile);
                    }

                    //Read email template data ...
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Template))
                        _finalTemplate = File.ReadAllText(Template);

                    //check replacements ...
                    if (Replacements.Count > 0)
                    {
                        //exception attached template..
                        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_finalTemplate))
                        {
                            throw new Exception("Set Template field (i.e. file path) while using replacement field");
                        }

                        foreach (var item in Replacements)
                        {
                            //Replace Required Variables...
                            _finalTemplate = _finalTemplate.Replace("<%" + item.Key.ToString() + "%>", item.Value.ToString());
                        }
                    }

                    //Set template...
                    mailMessage.Body = _finalTemplate;


                    //Send Email Using AWS SES...
                    var message = mailMessage;
                    var stream = FromMailMessageToMemoryStream(message);
                    using (AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient client = new AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient(
                               ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AWSAccessKey"].ToString(),
                               ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AWSSecretKey"].ToString(), 
                               RegionEndpoint.USWest2))
                    {
                        var sendRequest = new SendRawEmailRequest { RawMessage = new RawMessage { Data = stream } };
                        var response = client.SendRawEmail(sendRequest);

                        //return true ...
                    _isMailSent = true;

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    _isMailSent = false;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

            return _isMailSent;
        }

        private MemoryStream FromMailMessageToMemoryStream(MailMessage message)
        {
            Assembly assembly = typeof(SmtpClient).Assembly;

            Type mailWriterType = assembly.GetType("System.Net.Mail.MailWriter");

            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

            ConstructorInfo mailWriterContructor =
               mailWriterType.GetConstructor(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, new[] { typeof(Stream) }, null);
            object mailWriter = mailWriterContructor.Invoke(new object[] { stream });

            MethodInfo sendMethod =
               typeof(MailMessage).GetMethod("Send", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

            if (sendMethod.GetParameters().Length == 3)
            {
                sendMethod.Invoke(message, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, new[] { mailWriter, true, true }, null); // .NET 4.x
            }
            else
            {
                sendMethod.Invoke(message, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, new[] { mailWriter, true }, null); // .NET < 4.0 
            }

            MethodInfo closeMethod =
               mailWriter.GetType().GetMethod("Close", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            closeMethod.Invoke(mailWriter, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, new object[] { }, null);

            return stream;
        }
    }
```

3. Use above class to send mail anyone with attachment and template varibales replacement (it's optional)
   // Call this method to send your email

> public string SendEmailViaAWS()
>         {
>             string emailStatus = "";
>
> ```
>       //Create instance for send email...
>       AWSEmailSevice emailContaint = new AWSEmailSevice();
>       MailMessage emailStuff = new MailMessage();
>
>        //email subject..
>       emailStuff.Subject = "Your Email subject";
>
>         //region  Optional email stuff
>
>       //Templates to be used in email / Add your Html template path ..
>       emailContaint.Template = @"\Templates\MyUserNotification.html";
>
>       //add file attachment / add your file ...
>       emailContaint.AttachedFile = "\ExcelReport\report.pdf";
>
>
>
>         //Note :In case of template 
>         //if youe want to replace variables in run time 
>         //just add replacements like <%FirstName%>  ,  <%OrderNo%> , in HTML Template 
>
>
>         //if you are using some varibales in template then add 
>       // Hold first name..
>       var FirstName = "User First Name";
>
>       //  Hold email..
>       var OrderNo = 1236;
>
>
>       //firstname replacement..
>       emailContaint.Replacements.Add("FirstName", FirstName.ToString());
>       emailContaint.Replacements.Add("OrderNo", OrderNo.ToString());
>
>         // endregion option email stuff
>
>
>       //user OrderNo replacement...
>       emailContaint.To.Add(new MailAddress("TOEmail@gmail.com"));
>
>       //mail sent status
>       bool isSent = emailContaint.SendMail(emailStuff);
>
>       if(isSent)
>       {
>          emailStatus = "Success";
>       }
>       else
>       {
>       emailStatus = "Fail";
>       }
>          return emailStatus ;    }
> ```